# Connect cisco router with tp-link wireless adapter

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Is there a way to connect tp-link wireless adapter TL-WN722N with cisco router e4200? I want to setup router, that router can connect to the Internet via a wireless tp-link adapter (router has an USB slot for wireless adapter who make ap (adapter came with router) ). Then with cable via LAN to connect my computer to the Internet through the Cisco router who connected already to internet via tp-link adapter?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really all that clear what you're asking - but the Cisco E4200 is already a router & wireless Access Point.
The TP-Link wifi adapter doesn't go in the router, it goes in any computer you have which doesn't have built-in wifi.

See http://support.linksys.com/en-eu/support/routers/E4200
& http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=tl-wn722n

Comment: Maybe i havent been correctly, cisco e4200 give acess point to his internet who came via cabel,  but i want throw (router+ tp-link adapter) to connect to wifi network and then share internet via lan cabel to computer